# What are the Pocket Mortys crafting recipes?

Tags: pocket-mortys

What are the crafting recipes available in *Rick and Morty: Pocket Mortys*?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a full list:

|  | Item | Component 1 | Component 2 | Component 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Morty Manipulator Chip | Supercharged Battery | Circuit Board | Tin Can |
| 2. | Serum | Battery | Fleeb |  |
| 3. | Great Serum | Battery | Purified Fleeb |  |
| 4. | Sensational Serum | Supercharged Battery | Serum |  |
| 5. | Pure Serum | Supercharged Battery | Great Serum |  |
| 6. | Plutonic Rock | Battery | Bacteria Cell |  |
| 7. | Pure Plutonic Rock | Battery | Mutant Bacteria Cell |  |
| 8. | Halzinger | Battery | Fleeb | Bacteria Cell |
| 9. | Pure Halzinger | Battery | Purified Fleeb | Mutant Bacteria Cell |
| 10. | Level Up Mega Seed | Attack Mega Seed | Defense Mega Seed | Speed Mega Seed |
| 11. | Battery | Tin Can | Cable | Fleeb |
| 12. | Supercharged Battery | Battery | Turbulent Juice Tube |  |
| 13. | Microverse Battery | Supercharged Battery | Motherboard | Dark Matter Ball |
| 14. | Purified Fleeb | Fleeb | Turbulent Juice Tube |  |
| 15. | Mutant Bacteria Cell | Bacteria Cell | Turbulent Juice Tube |  |
| 16. | Dark Energy Ball | Fleeb | Bacteria Cell |  |
| 17. | Dark Matter Ball | Dark Energy Ball | Turbulent Juice Tube |  |
| 18. | Motherboard | Battery | Circuit Board | Cable |
| 19. | Dog Collar | Cable | Tin Can |  |
| 20. | Love Potion | Purified Fleeb | Mutant Bacteria Cell |  |
| 21. | Robot | Supercharged Battery | Motherboard |  |
| 22. | Butter Robot | Robot | Tin Can |  |
| 23. | Gwendolyn Doll | Robot | Love Potion |  |
| 24. | Time Crystal | Purified Fleeb | Dark Energy Ball |  |
| 25. | Time Stabilising Collar | Time Crystal | Dog Collar |  |
| 26. | Interdimensional Cable Box | Supercharged Battery | Motherboard | Time Crystal |
| 27. | Neutrino Bomb | Supercharged Battery | Motherboard | Dark Energy Ball |
| 28. | Interdimensional Goggles | Supercharged Battery | Time Crystal | Tin Can |
| 29. | IQ Enhancing Helmet | Supercharged Battery | Motherboard | Turbulent Tube Juice |
| 30. | Roy VR Headset | Interdimensional Goggles | IQ Enhancing Helmet |  |

Here's a screenshot showing these recipes with images:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Try this for items:

```
Circuit Board
Tin Can
Battery
Cable
Fleeb
Bacteria Cell
Turbulent Juice Tube
Attack Mega Seed
Defense Mega Seed
Speed Mega Seed
Morty Manipulator Chip=Supercharged Battery+Circuit Board+Tin Can
Serum=Battery+Fleeb
Great Serum=Battery+Purified Fleeb
Sensational Serum=Supercharged Battery+Serum
Pure Serum=Supercharged Battery+Great Serum
Plutonic Rock=Battery+Bacteria Cell
Pure Plutonic Rock=Battery+Mutant Bacteria Cell
Halzinger=Battery+Fleeb+Bacteria Cell
Pure Halzinger=Battery+Purified Fleeb+Mutant Bacteria Cell
Level Up Mega Seed=Attack Mega Seed+Defense Mega Seed+Speed Mega Seed
Battery=Tin Can+Cable+Fleeb
Supercharged Battery=Battery+Turbulent Juice Tube
Microverse Battery=Supercharged Battery+Motherboard+Dark Matter Ball
Purified Fleeb=Fleeb+Turbulent Juice Tube
Mutant Bacteria Cell=Bacteria Cell+Turbulent Juice Tube
Dark Energy Ball=Fleeb+Bacteria Cell
Dark Matter Ball=Dark Energy Ball+Turbulent Juice Tube
Motherboard=Battery+Circuit Board+Cable
Dog Collar=Cable+Tin Can
Love Potion=Purified Fleeb+Mutant Bacteria Cell
Robot=Supercharged Battery+Motherboard
Butter Robot=Robot+Tin Can
Gwendolyn Doll=Robot+Love Potion
Time Crystal=Purified Fleeb+Dark Energy Ball
Time Stabilising Collar=Time Crystal+Dog Collar
Interdimensional Cable Box=Supercharged Battery+Motherboard+Time Crystal
Neutrino Bomb=Supercharged Battery+Motherboard+Dark Energy Ball
Interdimensional Goggles=Supercharged Battery+Time Crystal+Tin Can
IQ Enhancing Helmet=Supercharged Battery+Motherboard+Turbulent Tube Juice
Roy VR Headset=Interdimensional Goggles+IQ Enhancing Helmet
```

...And this for Mortys:

```
#001 Morty  N/A​​
#002 Scruffy Morty  Rock​
#003 Unkempt Morty  Rock
#004 Hobo Morty Rock
#005 Old Morty  Paper
#006 Geriatric Morty    Paper
#007 Ancient Morty  Paper
#008 Rabbit Morty   Scissors
#009 Evil Rabbit Morty  Scissors
#010 No Eye Morty   Paper
#011 One Eye Morty  Paper
#012 Three Eye Morty    Scissors
#013 Test X1 Morty  Paper
#014 Test X46 Morty Paper
#015 Test x72 Morty Paper
#016 Self Defense Morty Rock
#017 Karate Morty   Rock
#018 No Mercy Morty Rock
#019 Mustache Morty Scissors
#020 Beard Morty    Scissors
#021 Hipster Morty  Scissors
#022 Ad Space Morty Paper
#023 Jerry's Game Morty Paper
#024 Pocket Mortys Morty    Paper
#025 Blue Shirt Morty   Scissors
#026 Red Shirt Morty    Paper
#027 Orange Shirt Morty Paper
#028 Green Shirt Morty  Paper
#029 Purple Shirt Morty Paper
#030 Rainbow Shirt Morty    Paper
#031 Eco-Alpha Morty    Scissors
#032 Exo-Omega Morty    Scissors
#033 Exo-Prime Morty    Scissors
#034 Spoon Morty    Rock
#035 Fork Morty Rock
#036 Spork Morty    Rock
#037 Peace Morty    Paper
#038 Hippie Morty   Paper
#039 Off the Grid Morty Paper
#040 Big Head Morty Rock
#041 Giant Head Morty   Rock
#042 Colossal Head Morty    Rock
#043 Spooky Morty   Paper
#044 Ghostly Morty  Paper
#045 Phantom Morty  Paper
#046 Double Morty   Scissors
#047 Triple Morty   Scissors
#048 Multi Morty    Scissors
#049 Greaser Morty  Rock
#050 Biker Morty    Rock
#051 Stray Cat Morty    Scissors
#052 Two Cat Morty  Scissors
#053 Crazy Cat Morty    Scissors
#054 Buff Morty Rock
#055 Wrestler Morty Rock
#056 Veiny Morty    Scissors
#057 No Skin Morty  Scissors
#058 Skeleton Morty Rock
#059 Magic Morty    Rock
#060 Mystic Morty   Rock
#061 Wizard Morty   Rock
#062 Telepathic Morty   Scissors
#063 Telekinetic Morty  Scissors
#064 Psychokinetic Morty    Scissors
#065 Swimmer Morty  Rock
#066 Mermaid Morty  Rock
#067 Reverse Mermaid Morty  Rock
#068 Business Morty Paper
#069 Gaseous Morty  Rock
#070 Sausage Morty  Scissors
#071 Shadow Morty   Scissors
#072 Aqua Morty Paper
#073 Cyclops Morty  Scissors
#074 Mini Morty Rock
#075 Cowboy Morty   Paper
#076 Robot Morty    Scissors
#077 Hammerhead Morty   Rock
#078 Guard Morty    Scissors
#079 Cronenberg Morty   N/A
#080 Mascot Morty   Paper
#081 Egg Morty  Rock
#082 One True Morty Rock
```

And if you like that, try it in a modestly interactive excel workbook ([mortybook version 1](http://bit.ly/mortybookv1)) - along with the items.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but this looks like a list of Mortys and their types rather than a list of crafting recipes.

Comment: You were right!  But no longer - I've added teh crafting recipes.

Comment: The latest update added 2 new recipes and also skips #10 for some reason (?) the new recipes create Paralyze Cure and Pure Curum, I don't know their ingredients... Yet.